# Generating UUIDs using attribute rules

Tags: arcgis-pro, attribute-table, arcade

Trying to automatically generate a uuid (preferably not a GlobalID) when a record is added to a dataset. It seems like the only [Esri suggested workflow](https://youtu.be/QPV_ydeoVY0) is to generate unique IDs is to use Arcade's [NextSequenceValue](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/data_functions/#nextsequencevalue). Any possible workarounds? Is there a way to run Python in attribute rules?

Comment: Do you actually want a UUID (a Universally unique identifier which is a 128-bit value, usually represented as 32 hexadecimal digits), or a UID (unique identifier), which can be any data type, but usually something that can be produced sequentially, and would be a better candidate for a number produced by NextSequenceValue.  See: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/blog/what-is-a-uuid/

Comment: @SonofaBeach I want an actual UUID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arcade has a text function called [Guid](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/text_functions/#guid) which will return a GUID as a text value.

As per the documentation, it supports an optional parameter which can be any of the following:

- `digits`
- `digits-hyphen`
- `digits-hyphen-braces`
- `digits-hyphen-parentheses`

Note, according to [Is there any difference between a GUID and a UUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6953207/1500125), there are subtle differences between GUID and UUID. But in short, they can be "treated as synonyms".